# Sending and Receiving large amount of data through TCPClient doesnot read all the data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Receiving bytes here in this code(server)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ByteLengthReading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartServer();            
        }

        private static TcpListener _listener;
        public static void StartServer()
        { 
            IPAddress localIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("119.43.29.182");
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, 8001);
            _listener = new TcpListener(ipLocal);
            _listener.Start();
            WaitForClientConnect();
        }

        private static void WaitForClientConnect()
        {
            object obj = new object();
            _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new System.AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), obj);
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {            
            try
            {
               TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
                clientSocket = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyn);
                HandleClientRequest clientReq = new HandleClientRequest(clientSocket);
                clientReq.StartClient();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            WaitForClientConnect();
        }

        public class HandleClientRequest
        {
            TcpClient _clientSocket;
            NetworkStream _networkStream = null;

            public HandleClientRequest(TcpClient clientConnected)
            {
                this._clientSocket = clientConnected;
            }

            public void StartClient()
            {
                _networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
                WaitForRequest();
            }

            public void WaitForRequest()
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

                _networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadCallback, buffer);
            }

            private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
            {                
                NetworkStream networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
                int read = -1;
                int totRead = 0;


                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Foo" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".txt", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    while ((read = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        totRead += read;
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        Console.WriteLine("Total Read" + totRead);
                        //fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, totRead);
                        //fileStream.Close();
                    }
                    fileStream.Close();
                }

            }

        }


}
```

Sending bytes (Client), Sending bytes of length 4047810. But the abover server code is recieving only 4039618 bytes. Please help someone. Don't know y? At the time of reading last set of data it is coming out of the while loop. Please test this code and tell me where the problem lies.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace ByteLengthSending
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("119.43.29.182"), 8001);
            //IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("119.43.29.182");
            //TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ipAd.ToString(), 8001);

            //NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int totread = 0;
            byte[] longBuffer = new byte[3824726];
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("C:/Foo.txt"))            
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    totread += read;
                    if (read <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    for (int sendBytes = 0; sendBytes < read; sendBytes += client.Send(buffer, sendBytes, read - sendBytes, SocketFlags.None))
                    {
                    }
                }                
            }
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Total Read" + totread);
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the data which has already been read when your callback is fired - *and* you're then reading the rest of the data synchronously, which pretty much negates the point of the first read being asynchronous in the first place. Do you really need asynchronous IO at this point? I suggest you get it working with synchronous IO first...

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to read the data Asynchronously only. Please tell what to do to read the whole data? Thanks for ur quick response!!

Comment: @user1805948: Why don't you use existing libraries that takes care of all the IO for you?

Comment: @jgauffin I didnt get u?? Which existing libraries? Can u elaborate pls.

Comment: I've built one. Want to see how you can send a file with it?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot it worked. As u said i was not reading the bytes of data which is being read at the time of readcallback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample which uses my library [Griffin.Framework](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.framework) to transmit a file (Apache license).

All you need to do is to install the nuget package "griffin.framework" and then create a console application and replace `Program` class with the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new ChannelTcpListener();
        server.MessageReceived = OnServerReceivedMessage;
        server.Start(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        var client = new ChannelTcpClient<object>(new MicroMessageEncoder(new DataContractMessageSerializer()),
            new MicroMessageDecoder(new DataContractMessageSerializer()));
        client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, server.LocalPort).Wait();
        client.SendAsync(new FileStream("TextSample.txt", FileMode.Open)).Wait();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnServerReceivedMessage(ITcpChannel channel, object message)
    {
        var file = (Stream) message;
        var reader = new StreamReader(file);
        var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(fileContents);
    }
}
```

The library can send/receive any type of stream of any size (as long as the size is known). The client will automatically create a `MemoryStream` or `FileStream` depending on the stream size.

Comment: It is totally a complicated one on which i cant rely.

Comment: creating your own socket client/server is a lot more complicated ;)